# Compass (ruby) error on Precise

Tags: ruby

I had Compass (a ruby gem) installed on Oneiric with no problems I have updated to Precise formatting / and keeping /home, so I needed to reinstall ruby.

I get this error now when I compile a SCSS file:

```
compass watch --trace
```

> > > Change detected at 12:45:09 to: style.scss
> > >       overwrite css/style.css
>
> Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
>   FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
>   be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
>   let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
>   - Travis Tilley
>
> > > Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
> > >       ArgumentError on line ["45"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
> > >         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:45:in `chop_basename'
> > >         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:101:in`cleanpath_aggressive'
> > >         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:89:in `cleanpath'
> > >         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:451:in`relative_path_from'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:81:in `split_path'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:69:in`run_callback'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:55:in `callback_action'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:35:in`update'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `block in modified'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in`each'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in`refresh'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in run'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in`each'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block in run'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in`loop'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `run'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in`run'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:87:in`perform'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in`execute'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in`run!'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in`call'
> > >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `<top (required)>'
> > >         /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in`load'
> > >         /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in `'

This error doesn't appear the first time I make a change to the scss file, but the second.

Any ideas?

In addition, compass "eats" one "s" in some files and, instead of compiling them as "style.css" (what it should be from the file's name) it does as "tyle.css".

EDIT: I am going to ask this on StackOverflow, since I think the problem is related to ruby itself and not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a problem with some libraries in the repos. Installing ruby with RVM solved it.